# Mips to C Conversion

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I am trying to convert this to C code, i know its going to be a forloop that starts from 50 and works it way down. But im lost in some of the other process such as when we get in the middle.

```
addi $t1, $0, 50
LOOP: lw $s1, 0($s0)
add $s2, $s2, $s1
lw $s1, 4($s0)
add $s2, $s2, $s1
addi $s0, $s0, 8
subi $t1, $t1, 1
bne $t1, $0, LOOP
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when we get in the middle"?

Comment: Why no comments (in your code) at all?

Answer (score 0):

Immediatly it may look something like that:

```
    t1 = 0 + 50;
LOOP:
    s1 = *s0;
    s2 = s2 + s1;
    s1 = *s0 + 4;
    s0 = s0 + 8;
    t1 = t1 - 1;
    if (t1 != 0) goto LOOP;
```

Translating `goto` to a `for` loop:

```
int *s0 = /* ... */;
int s2 = /* ... */;

for (t1 = 50; t1 != 0; t1--) {
    s2 += *s0;
    s0 += 8;
}
```

Comment: Since it adds both `0(s0)` and `4(s0)` to `s2`, shouldn't the "C" loop body be `s2 += s0[0]; s2 += s0[1]; s2 += 8;` ?

Answer (score 0):

It directly translates to:

```
int32_t* s0;
int32_t i = 50;
int32_t s2;
do {
    s2 += s0[j];
    s2 += s0[j+1];
    s0 += 2;
} while(--i);
```

The initial value of s0 and s2 are not given in the assembly code, but I am sure you can figure that out